# Processing Russian text file fails

Tags: python, unicode

I have this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
prefix = u"а"

rus_file = "rus_names.txt"
output = "rus_surnames.txt"

with codecs.open(rus_file, 'r', 'utf-8') as infile:
    with codecs.open(output, 'a', 'utf-8') as outfile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
        outfile.write(line+prefix)
```

And it gives me smth kinda chineese text in an output file. Even when I try to `outfile.write(line)` it gives me the same crap in an output. I just don't get it.
The purpose: I have a huge file with male surnames. I need to get the same file with female surnames. In russian it looks like this: `Ivanov - Ivanova | Иванов - Иванова`

Comment: ensure that original file is utf-8 encoded

Comment: Does your terminal support the font? Does `cat file` display the file correctly?

Comment: @ffledgling terminal is ok. When I try to `print` it gives me what I need. The problem shows when I'm trying to write it to a file.

Comment: @AndreyAtapin script reads everything as I need. When I try to print it, it prints appropriate data. It fails when I try to write in a newly created file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @AndreyAtapin was partially right. I've tried to add lines in a file which contains my previous mistakes with chineese characters. even flushing the file didn't help. But when I delete it and script creates it once again, it works! thanks.

Comment: Did you detect the original files encoding?

Comment: Yes. input file was ok6 but not the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lastname = str(line+prefix, 'utf-8')
outfile.write(lastname)
```

Comment: `File "rus.py", line 12, in <module>  
    outfile.write(lastname.encode('utf8'))  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: did you named variable lastname instead of flastname ?

Comment: Yes.. does it matter?